# Unable to append rows in Google Sheets using PHP API v4

Tags: php, google-sheets

I am trying out using Google Sheets as a CMS. I have managed to pull data from the sheet successfully and print it out on the page, but I am unable to **append** rows. When I check my console, there's a generic 500 error.

My code is below. What am I doing wrong?

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new \Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('mediaspin');
$client->setScopes([\Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS]);
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setAuthConfig('keys/blahblah.json');
$service = new Google_Service_Sheets($client);
$spreadsheetId = "obscured";

$range = 'sheet1';
$values = [    ["a", "b", "C", "D", "E"]   ];
$body = new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange([    'values' => $values ]);
$params = [    'valueInputOption' => "RAW" ];
$result = $service->spreadsheets_values->append($spreadsheet_id, $range, $body, $params);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The body of your request should simply be:

```js
{
  "values": [
    ["a", "b", "C", "D", "E"]
  ]
}
```

I think you are not constructing the `ValueRange` right though, from the documentation I don't see a constructor like you are using.

Try the request in the [API explorer](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append) and see if you get the 500 error. If so, it will likely contain the error message with more detail.

I was able to append the values no issues.